# PHP - reorder array by defined key to top

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to reorder a an array. Like

```
$array_to_reorder = array('home' => 'canada', 'school'=>'National School', 'phone' => '00808080', 'name'=>'john doe', '...'=>'...', '..'=>'...');
$shorting = array('name', 'phone', 'home');
```

I want to order `$array_to_reorder` as key defined in `$shorting`, and keep defined array to top of the array, and other array which was not defined at bottom.

I want this output:

```
$array_to_reorder = array(
'name'=>'john doe', 
'phone' => '00808080', 
'home' => 'canada', 
'school'=>'National School',
'...'=>'...', 
'..'=>'...'
);
```

Comment: post just example of how result should look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After updating the question. You could [flip](http://php.net/array_flip) array then use [merge](http://php.net/array_merge).

```
$array_to_reorder = array('home' => 'canada', 'school' => 'National School', 'phone' => '00808080', 'name' => 'john doe', '...' => '...', '..' => '...');
$shorting = array('name', 'phone', 'home');
$new_shorting = array_flip($shorting);
$result = array_merge($new_shorting, $array_to_reorder);
```

Comment: +1, this is what I'd have done, too. I've added the output and demo to your answer, but feel free to modify it as you see fit :)

Comment: but it will not work if that key has any value, like: name=>john doe, then it also stripe value. please tell me how to keep the value

Comment: @user007, I do not see any keys in the question.

Comment: sorry for that not writing the full array, here is the original array, `array('name'=> 'johndoe', phone=>'08889898', 'home'=>'cananda', '..'=> '..');`

Comment: Wow! its much better and very simple solution. thanks